# DataContract inherit from a non-DataContract base class

Tags: c#, serialization

Is it possible (and if so then how) to inherit from a base class that doesn't implement `[DataContract]` and tell the serializer to ignore it?

So something like

```
//Non-accessible, non-[DataContract] class
public class ThirdPartyOrFrameworkClass
{
    public void ConvenienceMethod()
    {
        //Code
    }
    //Rest of the class
}

[DataContract (IgnoreBaseClassWhenSerializing = true)]
public class SomeStateClass : ThirdPartyOrFrameworkClass
{
    [DataMember]
    string _data;

    //Rest of the class
}
```

If not, what's the solution to using a class that doesn't implement the `[DataContract]` attribute?

I'd prefer to use the `DataContractSerializer` than the `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: Well in the standard scenario you simple control the code for your data contracts. Why do you want to expose a contract that you can't control?

Comment: For convenience. It's not a huge problem, I can get around it by just using a POCO (like you should?). I just wanted to derive from a base class that has a few convenience methods.

Comment: Yes I would go for POCO implementation. If you want to use the ThirdParty class on the service side I would have have a mapping layer that created that class for me (and then use it in the business layer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to your question in NO (if you can't change the ThirdPartyOrFrameworkClass  source code).